# Synonym request: [esports] -> [competitive-gaming]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a [competitive-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming), and we have a [esports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esports). These are basically the same, and should be synonymized, but the question is, what direction should they be synonymized in? Should [competitive-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming) be used, or should [esports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esports) be used?

Answer (score 12):

I wouldn't trust Wikipedia when common sense is at stake. It should be also noted that [competitive-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming) tag has 3 questions and [esports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esports) has only 1. It's not a good enough number to judge which is more popular among users, though.

When you're not familiar with terminology, you're going to try and describe something with words understandable by largest audience. And I don't think most users would expect a site such as SE to predominantly use topic-specific terminology, when it's main goal is to be friendly to as many users as possible. That's why we don't see as much lingo used for programming sites as tags' primary names. Surely, each area of human activity has its own terminology, but that doesn't mean we have to go full academic on people. That wouldn't be nice.

I vote for [competitive-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming).

Comment: Current number of questions doesn't matter.  We're not running a popularity contest.

Comment: @MBraedley It does, however, indicate which tag people find more natural to use. (Not in these low numbers, though.)

Answer (score 4):

[esports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esports) makes the most sense as the primary tag.

esports is the term used by tournaments such as DreamHack and MLG. Wikipedia also has  a page on [Esports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_sports), and redirects [Competitive Gaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_gaming) to the esports page. The [top Google result](https://www.google.com/search?q=competitive+gaming) for Competitive Gaming turns up the Wikipedia esports page as well.

Comment: I can play Monopoly competitively, yet its not a sport. I can play Bomberman competitively, yet its not an esport. [competitive-gaming] has a much broader topic area than [esport], which is generally reserved for televised/streamed competitions

Comment: I feel the need to point out that the top google result for Competitive Gaming turning up Esports and the fact that Wikipedia redirects from Competitive gaming to Esports leads to the former being biased by the latter.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As of January 15th, [esports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esports) has been synonymized with [competitive-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming).

[image: competitive-gaming ← esports]

Answer (score -3):

I see these tags as entirely different subjects as noted in both answers.

[esports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esports) as a genre is the video game equivalent to talking about the "Majors" (See Baseball, Basketball, American Football, Futbol, etc) as the U.S. recognizes Video Games players from other countries as "Athletes", this is where I would expect a question such as "What are the rules regarding the MLG variant of Team Deathmatch for Call of Duty: Ghosts?".

Whereas [competitive-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/competitive-gaming) is the industry of Competitive Gaming where questions such as "Which companies fund the Texas MLG Tournament?"

But this is my personal preference and even though I see the difference I also see the similarities in them.